# What is the correct way to create partitions for both Windows and Linux on an Western Digital’s Advanced Format 1 TB Hard Drive?

Tags: installation, dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive

What is the correct way to create partitions for both Windows and Linux on an Western Digital’s Advanced Format 1 TB Hard Drive?

### I want partitions to be like this:

### => Primary:

### 325 GB Windows 7 x64

---

### => Extended:

125 GB D Drive

095 GB E Drive

135 GB Ubuntu x86

### 245 GB Fedora x64

6 GB SWAP for Ubuntu and Fedora.

How do I do the partitioning using Gparted ?This is what I have now:
[image]

Im seeing this error in Disks ! The harddrive is fairly new. I have purchased that this month. [image]

1. My question is how can I fix the current partition table without re-partitioning?
2. If I have to partition then what vlaue will be optimal for the Advanced format hardisk ?
3. How to do the calculation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run into Live Mode using a Latest version of Ubuntu ISO or Gparted DVD. Later, while partitioning with "Gparted", when Gparted prompts for 1 MB left over space before the first Partition just allow it (This is the most Vital step.)

By default "Align to MiB" will be selected. Don't Change that. Do the rest of the partitioning normally. After you finish, to check whether the partitions are aligned properly; issue the following command on terminal:

> sudo fdisk -l

If the output says /dev/sda1 start = 2048 and **DOES NOT says** "Partition X does not start on physical sector boundary."  then you are good to go.

Another way is to use GPT partitioning scheme instead of MS-DOS. If you use GPT, then there is no special 1 MB free space allotment before the first partition is required. Gparted will make all the partitions 4k aligned by default.

For GPT Partitions:

> To verify a partition is aligned, query it using /usr/bin/blockdev as
>   shown below, if a '0' is returned, the partition is aligned:

```
# blockdev --getalignoff /dev/<partition>
0
```

Answer (score 0):

im not really sure on how to partition in ubuntu, as I am still new to learning ubuntu however, may I ask you this, does it have to be partitioned in ubuntu? if you are having trouble with it you could always back everything up, you could uninstall ubuntu and install windows 7 which would be really simple to partition in the disk management, and then you could reinstall ubuntu

Comment: I have a triple boot system. Ubuntu, Windows and Fedora.